# Multi Threads Socket Java

Tags: java, multithreading, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

My client:

```
class Read_ChatClient extends Thread{

private static Socket client;
private  String user;
static ArrayList<SingleChatF> chatFrames = new ArrayList<>();

public Read_ChatClient(Socket client, String username) {
    this.client = client;
    this.user = username;
}

public void checkAddNewFrame(String sourceName, String desName, String mess){
    boolean exitFrame = false;
    int index = 0;
    for(SingleChatF frame: chatFrames) {
        System.out.println(index + "; " + frame.getSourceName() + "; " + frame.getDestName());
        if (frame.Match(sourceName, desName)) {
            frame.gettxtchatall().append(mess + "\n");
            System.out.println("Founded frame: " + sourceName + "; " + desName);
            exitFrame = true;
            break;
        };
        index++;
    }
    if(!exitFrame) {
        SingleChatF newFrame = new SingleChatF(this.client, sourceName, desName);
        newFrame.setVisible(true);
        newFrame.gettxtchatall().append(mess + "\n");
        chatFrames.add(newFrame);
        System.out.println("Created new frame: " + sourceName + "; " + desName);
    }

}
@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + " - Read_ChatClient");
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    try {
        dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(" - Read_ChatClient client.getInputStream() OK");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(" - Read_ChatClient......");
            String sms = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(" - Read_ChatClient.sms: "+sms);
            if (sms.contains("login_successed")){
                System.out.println(" - Read_ChatClient: Join()");
                String[] info = sms.split(";");
                String username = info[1];
                String[] onlineuserList = info[2].split(",");
                if (username.equalsIgnoreCase(user)) {
                    MultiThreads_LoginClient.setLoginF(false);
                    MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame = new ChatF(user, client);
                    MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.setVisible(true);
                    JTable OnlineTab = MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.getjtableonlineuser();
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) OnlineTab.getModel();
                    for (String name : onlineuserList) {
                       model.addRow(new String[]{name});
                    }
                }else if(!username.equalsIgnoreCase(user)){
                     MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.getjtableonlineuser().setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null,new String[]{"Online Users"}));
                    for (String name : onlineuserList) {
                        JTable OnlineTab = MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.getjtableonlineuser();
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) OnlineTab.getModel();
                        model.addRow(new String[]{name}); 
                    }
                    MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.gettxtchatall().append(username+" da ket noi\n");
                }
            } else if (sms.contains("login_failed;")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Failed");
            } else if (sms.contains("user_actived")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User's activing");
            }else if(sms.contains("updateOnlineUserList")){
                String[] list = sms.split(":");
                String[] newList = list[1].split(",");
                MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.getjtableonlineuser().setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null,new String[]{"Online Users"}));
                for (String name : newList) {
                    JTable OnlineTab = MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.getjtableonlineuser();
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) OnlineTab.getModel();
                    model.addRow(new String[]{name});
                }
                System.out.println("updateOnlineUserList:"+sms);
            }else if(sms.contains("chatPrivate")){
                //{ChatPrivate}:{Source_name}:{des_name}:{mess}:{host:port}
                System.out.println("ClientRead_chatPrivate: " + sms);
                String[] content = sms.split(";");
                String sourceName = content[1];
                String desName = content[2];
                String mess = content[3];
                checkAddNewFrame(desName, sourceName, mess);
            }else if(sms.contains("AlertAlert_SendFilesToClient")){
                System.out.println("AlertAlert_SendFilesToClient");
                currentThread().wait();
                Read_FileClient rf = new Read_FileClient(client);
                rf.start();
            }else{
                MultiThreads_LoginClient.chatFrame.gettxtchatall().append("\n" + sms);
                System.out.println(sms);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       try {
           currentThread().wait();
           Read_FileClient rf = new Read_FileClient(client);
           rf.start();
           //dis.close();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read_ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}}
```

My Server:

```
class Read_ChatServer extends Thread{
private static Socket socket;
private static SingleChatFrame_SV singlechatFrame;
public static void setsocket(Socket socket){
    Read_ChatServer.socket = socket;
}

public Read_ChatServer(Socket client) {
    this.socket = client;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Read_ChatServer");
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Checking socket.getInputStream()");
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("OK socket.getInputStream()");
        while (true) {
            String sms = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(" - Read_ChatServer: " + sms);
            if (sms.contains("Login_Requiere")) {
                //{Login_Requiere};{username};{password}
                try {
                    dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    System.out.println("Trying login for user " + sms);
                    String[] contents = sms.split(";");

                    String info[] = sms.split(";");//info[1]: username  - info[2]:pass
                    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
                    String query = "Select *from `info` where `user`=? AND `pw`=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst;
                    ResultSet rs;
                    try {
                        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        pst.setString(1, info[1]);
                        pst.setString(2, info[2]);
                        rs = pst.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            // login;{success: true, onlineuser: ["", ""]}
                            // chat;
                            if (!MultiThreads_LoginServer.checkuserexits(info[1])) {
                                accountinfo temp = new accountinfo(socket, info[1]);
                                MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("Da ket noi " + info[1] + "\n");
                                System.out.println("Da ket noi " + socket);
                                MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList.add(temp);
                                showonlineuser();
                                String statusString = "login_successed;" + info[1] + ";" + MultiThreads_LoginServer.convertoString();
                                BroadCastUserListToAllClients wu = new BroadCastUserListToAllClients(statusString);
                                wu.start();
                            } else {
                                dos.writeUTF("user_actived; ; ");
                            }

                        } else {

                            dos.writeUTF("login_failed; ; ");
                            //dos.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    DBConnection.closeConnection(con);
                    MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("User: " + info[1] + "\tPass: " + info[2] + "\n");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(" - Error Read_LoginServer: " + e.getMessage());
                    try {
                        dis.close();
                        dos.close();
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Read_LoginServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }else if (sms.contains("exit")) {
                String[] exitInfo = sms.split(":");
                String notify = "Ngat ket noi voi : " + exitInfo[1]+"\n";
                try {
                    MultiThreads_LoginServer.remove_user(exitInfo[1]);
                    if (MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList.isEmpty()) {
                        MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("No User Online!");
                    } else {
                        showonlineuser();
                        MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append(notify + "\n");
                        System.out.println(" - Read_ChatServer: " + notify);
                        for (accountinfo item : MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList) {
                            dos = new DataOutputStream(item.socket.getOutputStream());
                            dos.writeUTF(notify);
                            //dos.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    String currentList = convertoString();
                    BroadCastUserListToAllClients broad = new BroadCastUserListToAllClients("updateOnlineUserList: " + currentList);
                    broad.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showonlineuser();
                    MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append(notify + "\n");
                    MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("No User Online!");
                }

            } else if(sms.contains("chatPrivate")){
                System.out.println("server_chatPrivate: "+ sms);
                //{ChatPrivate};{Source_name};{des_name};{mess}
                String[] content = sms.split(";");
                String s_name = content[1];
                String d_name = content[2];
                if(d_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Server")){
                   //
                }else{
                    for(accountinfo item:MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList){
                    if(item.username.equalsIgnoreCase(d_name)){
                        dos = new DataOutputStream(item.socket.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeUTF(sms);
                    }
                }
                }

            }else if(sms.contains("Alert_SendFiles")){
                System.out.println("Alert_SendFiles");
                String[] content = sms.split(":");
                String des_name = content[1];

                AlertAlert_SendFilesToClient alert = new AlertAlert_SendFilesToClient(des_name);
                alert.start();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("-Alert_SendFiles: pass alert");
                currentThread().wait();
                Read_FileServer rf = new Read_FileServer(socket);
                rf.start();


            }else{
                MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append(sms + "\n");
                for (accountinfo item : MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList) {

                     dos = new DataOutputStream(item.socket.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(sms);
                    //dos.flush();
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No user online!");
        System.out.println(" - Error Read_ChatServer: " + e.getMessage());
        try {
            dis.close();
            //dos.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(" - Error Read_ChatServer: " + ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Read_ChatServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}}
```

My class Send file:

```
class Write_SendFiles extends Thread{
private Data_file data;
private Socket client;
public Write_SendFiles(Data_file data,Socket client) {
  this.data = data;
  this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Write_SendFiles");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
         System.out.println("-Write_SendFiles:"+data.getfilename());
        oos.writeObject(data);

        System.out.println("-Write_SendFiles: pass send file");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /*try {
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
             System.out.println("-Write_SendFiles Err:"+ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Write_SendFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }*/
          System.out.println("-Write_SendFiles Err:"+ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(Write_SendFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}   }
```

class Read_FileClient extends Thread{

```
private Socket client;

public Read_FileClient(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Client file");
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("-Server file: pass new obj");
        try {
            Data_file datafile = (Data_file) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("-Server file:read file successfully");
            boolean exitingChatFrame_file = false;
            for (SingleChatF single : Read_ChatClient.chatFrames) {
                exitingChatFrame_file = single.Match(datafile.getdes_name(), datafile.getdes_name());
                System.out.println("File - Finding frame: Source=" + datafile.getdes_name() + "; Dest=" + datafile.getdes_name() + "; " + exitingChatFrame_file);
                if (exitingChatFrame_file) {
                    JList FilesTranfer = single.getjlisttranfer();
                    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                    FilesTranfer.setModel(model);
                    model.addElement(datafile);
                    System.out.println("Founded");
                    single.gettxtchatall().append("Getting file...");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!exitingChatFrame_file) {
                System.out.println("ClientRead_chatPrivate: not active");
                SingleChatF newFrame = new SingleChatF(this.client, datafile.getdes_name(), datafile.getdes_name());
                newFrame.setVisible(true);
                JList FilesTranfer = newFrame.getjlisttranfer();
                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                FilesTranfer.setModel(model);
                model.addElement(datafile);
                chatFrames.add(newFrame);
                newFrame.gettxtchatall().append("Getting file...");
            }

            //client.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read_ChatClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Read_FileClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}}
```

My Server read file:

```
class Read_FileServer extends Thread{
private Socket client;

public Read_FileServer(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Server Read_FileServer");
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        try {
            Data_file datafile = (Data_file)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("-Server Read_FileServer: read file successfully");
            for(accountinfo item : MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList){
                if(item.username.equalsIgnoreCase(datafile.getdes_name())){
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(item.socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(datafile);
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read_FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        try {
            ois.close();
            oos.close();

        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read_FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }

        Logger.getLogger(Read_FileServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

But now i have the function is send file. So i have to use ObjectInputStream and Object OutputStream .The problems is 2 type difference between DataInputStream,DataOutputStream and ObjectInputStream,OutputStream.How can i put thread of ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStreadm to my class. thanks you!

Comment: 1. Stop creating new `DataInput/OutputStreams` and `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` on the same socket. Keep using the same ones. 2. If you're using `DataInput/OutputStreams` on one end you can't use `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` on the other end. Make up your mind. if you're only using `read/writeUTF()`, stick to `DataInput/OutputStreams`. If you're going to send objects, use `ObjectInput/OutputStreams` at both ends. And, again, only create them once each.

Comment: but i have to use both, because file can not  use DataInput/OutputStreams

Comment: You don't have to use both, because you *can't* use both, and any requirement you have dreamed up that says otherwise is imaginary. If you have to use object streams in one place, you have to use them everywhere. There are no two ways about this.

Comment: i'm building an chat application , so i almost use read/writeUTF(), but when i send file i have to use read/writeobject

Comment: So? Are you aware that `ObjectInputStream.readUTF()` exists? and `ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF()`?

Answer (score -1):

```java
try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStreamdos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())){
                    System.out.println("Trying login for user " + sms);
                    String[] contents = sms.split(";");
                    String info[] = sms.split(";");//info[1]: username  - info[2]:pass
                    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
                    String query = "Select *from `info` where `user`=? AND `pw`=?";
                    PreparedStatement pst;
                    ResultSet rs;
                    try {
                        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        pst.setString(1, info[1]);
                        pst.setString(2, info[2]);
                        rs = pst.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            // login;{success: true, onlineuser: ["", ""]}
                            // chat;
                            if (!MultiThreads_LoginServer.checkuserexits(info[1])) {
                                accountinfo temp = new accountinfo(socket, info[1]);
                                MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("Da ket noi " + info[1] + "\n");
                                System.out.println("Da ket noi " + socket);
                                MultiThreads_LoginServer.accountinfoList.add(temp);
                                showonlineuser();
                                String statusString = "login_successed;" + info[1] + ";" + MultiThreads_LoginServer.convertoString();
                                BroadCastUserListToAllClients wu = new BroadCastUserListToAllClients(statusString);
                                wu.start();
                            } else {
                                dos.writeUTF("user_actived; ; ");
                            }

                        } else {

                            dos.writeUTF("login_failed; ; ");
                            //dos.flush();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    DBConnection.closeConnection(con);
                    MultiThreads_LoginServer.chatFrame_Server.gettxtchatall().append("User: " + info[1] + "\tPass: " + info[2] + "\n");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(" - Error Read_LoginServer: " + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: what's you mean?

Comment: ```try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStreamdos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))``` can you explain this to me?

Comment: in my post code dont have DataOutputStreamdos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()). so i think it is an answer

Comment: @Ochimot You do indeed have it, and he still has to explain.